# how can you count the number of packet losses in a file transfer?

Tags: networking, ping, wifi

One of my networks course projects has to do with 802.11 protocol.

Me and my parther thought about exploring the "hidden terminal" problem, simulating it.

We've set up a private network. We have 2 wireless terminals that will attempt to send a file
to a 3rd terminal that is connected to the router via ethernet. RTS/CTS will be disabled.

To compare results, we'd like to measure the number of packet collisions that occured during the transfer so as to conclude that is due to RTS being disabled.

We've read that it is imposible to measure packet collisions as it is basically noise. We'll have to make do with counting the packets that didnt recieve an "ACK". Basically, the number of retransmitions.
How can we do that?

I suggested that instead of sending a file, we could make the 2 wireless terminals ping the 3rd terminal continually. The ping feature automatically counts the ping packets that didnt recieve the "pong". Do you think its a viable approach?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll get incorrect results. `Ping` is an application, i.e. working at application (highest) level of the network. `802.11` protocol operates at `MAC` layer - there are at least 2 layers separating between ping and 802.11. Whatever retransmissions happen at MAC layer - they are hidden by the layers above it. You'll see failure in `ping` only if all the retransmissions initiated by lower levels have failed.

You need to work on the same level that you're investigating - in your case it's the MAC layer. You can use a sniffer (google for it) to get the statistics you want.